# What do I do with this aureole?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

I've just opened the lock with Logfella's key (after recovering it from Side B), but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with this aureole:

[image]

I've come across many similar objects in the quest thus far, but this one has its own instructions with it.  (Don't I wish they all did...)  No matter what I've done to the aureole, I've gotten no reaction.

I even tried chomping down on a random mushroom I found while exploring the wilderness, and a lot of red dots appeared, but there was nothing particularly helpful that occurred as a result.

How do I properly stimulate this particular aureole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, some further investigation led me to the conclusion that the hint is *full of it.*

The puzzle on this particular screen involves tapping the 8 trees in this area, and has nothing to do with the aureole itself.  There's a particular pattern to the tree tapping - I managed to solve it by:

> tapping the larger trees at the top right, then the smaller trees in the same area.  After this, I tapped the larger and then the smaller trees in the lower left hand area.

Comment: It took me some time, but I did the left side first and then the right one, also in that order, so I guess both ways are contemplated

Answer (score 1):

You have click the thicker tree logs on the screen, I think there were seven or eight in total, and click them using the right order (I did it aleatory, but my guess is that it has to be done from thicker to thiner).

Oh, and I also spent some time to guess that there are trees in both left and right side of the screen.

You can also use a mushroom to find hints about what to do :D